# Python: None and Try Except

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, try-catch

I am making a test harness for a budget program. The individual purchases are represented with the Item class. If the class is initialized incorrectly, I want to return None. However, when I run my test harness, it doesn't detect the variable as being None. Why is the test harness not detecting the Item as None?

```
def __init__(self, nameItem, costItem):

    try: 

        if costItem < 0.00 or type(nameItem) is not str:
            self = None
        else:

            if len(nameItem) < 1:
                self = None
            else:
                self.name = nameItem
                self.cost = round(costItem,2)

                if self.name == None or self.cost == None:
                    self = None
    except:
        self = None
```

```
#Test Case

currentTest = currentTest + 1
    print("Test" ,currentTest,":Create invalid item using negative cost.")
    try:
        testItem = Item("Coffee",-1.00)
        if testItem is None:
            print("Made None value when given incorrect data:TEST PASSED")
            passTests = passTests + 1
        else:
            raise TypeError
    except TypeError:
        print("Error when creating item, created item instead of detecing error:TEST FAILED")
        failedTests.insert(failedCount,currentTest)
        failedCount = failedCount + 1
    except:
        print("Error when conducting test:TEST FAILED")
        failedTests.insert(failedCount,currentTest)
        failedCount = failedCount + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `__init__()` (or *any* class method for that matter), `self` is a *local* variable, bound to the object this method was called for. Assigning to it will only affect the binding of that local variable, it will *not* change the actual reference to the object that exists outside of the method.

By the time you get to `__init__`, the object is already allocated - you *may* be able to reverse that with some "trickery" but I'm not sure it would be a good idea, even *if* possible.

The *normal* <sup>(a)</sup> way to handle initialisation issues is simply to throw an exception which can be caught to rebind the variable appropriately (or do something else as required):

```
try:
    item = className()
except:
    item = None
```

You could even provide a helper function to do the heavy lifting for you, so construction still only took one line, something like:

```
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self, makeFail):
        if makeFail: raise Exception("ouch")

def tryMake(cls, *args):
    try:
        return cls(*args)
    except:
        return None

print(tryMake(ClassName, False)) # equiv: print(ClassName(False))
print(tryMake(ClassName, True))
```

As you can see from the output, it converts failed construction into `None`:

```
<__main__.ClassName object at 0x7f7ed1e38c70>
None
```

---

However, another possibility exists, if you *really* want to do something like what you propose but don't want to catch exceptions or rebind through a helper function.

There is *another* magic function `__new__` that is called before `__init__`, and which *is* capable of returning a different type. Only if it returns the requested type will Python then call `__init__` on it.

Hence you can define the `__new__` call to check the price and refuse to instantiate the type if it's invalid, as per the example code below:

```
class Item:
    def __new__(cls, item, price):
        if price < 0:
            return None
        return super(Item, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, item, price):
        self.item = item
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.item}, {self.price})"

print(Item("Coffee", 4.50))
print(Item("Tea", -1))
print(Item("Biscuit", 2.75))
```

The output of this seems to be what you desire:

```
(Coffee, 4.5)
None
(Biscuit, 2.75)
```

Now this is probably not something that *I* would do, instead preferring to throw the exception in `__init__()` and let the caller take care of it in whatever manner they choose (including using a helper function if so desired).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Defined as:

> **normal** *(n)* - in such a manner as to not cause seasoned Python developers to question your sanity :-)

Comment: The purpose of Returning None is to indicate erroneous input. Is using New better than using Init when trying to bubble up error handling?

Comment: @Ehedges, I'd probably avoid it myself and just throw an exception in `__init__`, letting caller handle it. The use of `__new__` just provides a way to do this without an exception or helper function. I've modified the answer to show my preference a little more strongly.

Comment: None is to try and indicate erroneous input. I'm coming from a C background, so I was trying to use it as a proper return, such as NULL to indicate issues.

Answer (score -1):

Might have something to do with your value of -1.00, try assigning it as a float inside the function or the init. E.g:

def **init**(self, nameItem, float(costItem)):

If costItem < float(0.00)

testItem = Item("Coffee",float(-1.00))

Answer (score -1):

In your `__init__` function there is a conceptual mistake: setting *self* to **None** you are creating a new label named *self* with **None** value, you are not setting the original object to **None**.

When `__init__` is called, the object it has just been created.

If you want to inhibit the object creation you have o use `__new__`, but you have to use an *exception*, it is not possible to nullify the object value.